# How to use rsuite - React Suite range slider?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, rangeslider, rsuite

Good evening,
I'm using the UI framework [rsuite](https://rsuitejs.com/) (React suite) for the first time, the setup was just fine, but when i wanted to use the API of the component Slider - Range slider, the labels and the tooltips are not working.

Here is some code :

```
import { RangeSlider } from 'rsuite';
export default ()=> {

return (
    <RangeSlider defaultValue={[10, 50]} max={100} min={0} />
)

}
```

The page loads with no errors, but i still can't find a way to use the [API](https://rsuitejs.com/components/slider/#%3CRangeSlider%3E) renderMark.
is there any easy way to do this ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

I could not reproduce the problem you described on codesandbox.
https://codesandbox.io/s/rsuite-rangeslider-e24ft